# Log4net issue with RollingFileAppender

Tags: asp.net, configuration, log4net

Following is the code:

```
  <log4net debug="lse">
    <!-- Define some output appenders -->
    <appender name="trace" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender, log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Add StrcuturedFN logger-->
    <appender name="StructuredFNLoggerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Log\Log.txt"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ff} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
    <root>
      <priority value="WARN"/>
      <appender-ref ref="StructuredFNLoggerAppender"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="StructuredFNLogger.Logging">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="StructuredFNLoggerAppender"/>
    </logger>

  </log4net>
```

The logger is logging but new file is not created when the size of the file grows more then 10MB.

Comment: why do you reference the appender in the root and the StructuredFNLogger.Logging logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help; Here is  section of a working app config that is using RollingFileAppender.

```
<log4net>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="child" />
            <param name="CountDirection" value="1" />
            <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
            <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="-1" />
            <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="Header" value="DateTime    Thread  Level   Logger  Message%newline" />
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d   %t  %-5p    %c  %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="delivery.log" />
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="Header" value="DateTime    Thread  Level   Logger  Message%newline" />
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d   %t  %-5p    %c  %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
            <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="[%thread] %-5level %logger%newline%message" />
            </layout>
        </appender>     
        <!--
        <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender" >
            <param name="Threshold" value="FATAL" />
            <param name="SmtpHost" value="-fill in-" />
            <param name="Subject" value="FUSION RIS Delivery Service " />
            <param name="To" value="-fill in-" />
            <param name="From" value="-fill in-" />
            <param name="Lossy" value="false" />
            <param name="BufferSize" value="1" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%newline%d [%thread] %-5level %logger%newline%message" />
            </layout>
        </appender>     
        -->
        <root>
            <level value="WARN" />
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
            <!--<appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />-->
            <!--<appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />-->
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn on internal debugging and see if there is anything going on that shouldn't.

from the [log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html):

> There are 2 different ways to enable
>   internal debugging in log4net. These
>   are listed below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

> The preferred method
>   is to specify the
>   log4net.Internal.Debug option in the
>   application's config file.
>
> Internal debugging can also be enabled
>   by setting a value in the
>   application's configuration file (not
>   the log4net configuration file, unless
>   the log4net config data is embedded in
>   the application's config file). The
>   log4net.Internal.Debug application
>   setting must be set to the value true.
>   For example:  
>       
>           
>         This setting is read immediately on
>   startup an will cause all internal
>   debugging messages to be emitted.
>
> To enable log4net's internal debug
>   programmatically you need to set the
>   log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging
>   property to true. Obviously the sooner
>   this is set the more debug will be
>   produced. Internal debugging messages
>   are written to the console and to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system. If
>   the application does not have a
>   console the messages logged there will
>   be lost. Note that an application can
>   redirect the console stream by setting
>   the System.Console.Out. The Trace
>   system will by default send the
>   message to an attached debugger (where
>   the messages will appear in the output
>   window). If the process does not have
>   a debugger attached then the messages
>   are sent to the system debugger. A
>   utility like DebugView from
>   http://www.sysinternals.com may be
>   used to capture these messages.
>
> As log4net internal debug messages are
>   written to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system it is
>   possible to redirect those messages to
>   a local file. You can define a trace
>   listener by adding the following to
>   your application's .config file:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"

                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ... </configuration>
```

> Make sure that the process running your
>   application has permission to write to
>   this file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of a rolling file appender:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="../Logs/Web-Log.xml"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout">
            <param name="Prefix" value=""/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: FYI your code block was hiding the appender definition so I didn't notice it before I posted this. Your appender is very similar to mine so this may not be much help.